# Can not add uniqueidentifier type column in columnstore non-clustered index

Tags: uniqueidentifier, non-clustered-index, columnstore

Im trying  to create non-clustered COLUMNSTORE  index on my fact table including some key columns.... but when selecting columns of table to add in index  i don't see all of the columns which are uniqueidentifier type. There are all column types exept uids in menu.

Is it possible to add uniqueidentifier type in non-clustered COLUMNSTORE  index ?

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using and update your question with the full DDL (including any keys/indexes) of the table(s)